# Why won't my tkinter window move further than 1 pixel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter window bounce around the screen like a ball in Pong, but it will only move 1 pixel in each direction and back again. What have I done wrong?

main.py:

```
import tkinter
from time import sleep

window = tkinter.Tk()

screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

window.title('VIRUS.EXE')

width, height = 300, 150
x, y, = 0, 0

x_vel = 1
y_vel = 1

while True:

    sleep(0.1)

    if x + width >= screen_width or x <= 0:
        x_vel = -x_vel

    if y + width >= screen_height or y <= 0:
        y_vel = -y_vel

    x += x_vel
    y += y_vel

    window_string = str(width) + 'x' + str(height) + '+' + str(x) + '+' + str(y)

    window.geometry(window_string)

    window.update()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Perhaps you should print out the value of `x`, `y`, `x_vel`, and `y_vel` each time through the loop to see if they are what you think they should be.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried that. The values of x_vel and y_vel are only 1 or -1 and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `+` instead of `-`

```
if x + width >= screen_width or x <= 0:
    x_vel = +x_vel

if y + width >= screen_height or y <= 0:
    y_vel = +y_vel
```

Edit: this may point you in the right direction:

```
if x <= screen_width or x <= 0:
    x_vel = +x_vel
    x += x_vel

if y <= (screen_height -200)or y <= 0:
    y_vel = +y_vel
    y += y_vel
```

Comment: Thanks. The window moves, but it doesn't change direction when it reaches the end of the screen. Edit: I found out why--the screen width function returns a number bigger than the width of my screen for some reason.

Comment: The window collides with the edges of my screen, but it doesn't bounce back the other way.

Comment: I had to modify your code a bit but it works now. Thanks.

Comment: @Ajesh I have a working solution that never stoppes bouncing if you are interested. [Here](http://pasted.co/0d2d5747)